# How to have control on the object that started a background process in android, after the application is closed?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, background-process

I used AlarmManager to schedule recurring background task. When an alarm is triggered, a Pending Intent is broadcast by the Android system. The receiver class simply displays a toast repeatedly, every 10 sec. I have created the intent in **startAlarm** method, and cancel in **cancelAlarm** method.
My problem is: when I close the application after creating the alarm, the toast is getting displayed continuously, and when I reopen the app, I lose control on the object that created the background task, so I cannot cancel it. Help?

Here are the methods that control the alarm :

```
public void startAlarm(Context context)
{
    ser=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, serviceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
    ser.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pi);
}
public void cancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    if (ser != null) 
    {
        ser.cancel(pi);
        ser=null;
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And here is the receiver class for the alarm:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
    {
    Toast.makeText(arg0, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'I lose control on the object that created the background task, so I cannot cancel it'? What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 0):

for control of background service you can use

```
Process.killProcess(int pid)
ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(String packageName)
```

or forceclose

```
       Intent intent = new Intent(yourCurrentActivity.this,yourNextActivity.class);  
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
       startActivity(intent);  
       android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

or for alarm manager u can blew code to cancel alarm.
Depending on your app, you may want to include the ability to cancel the alarm. To cancel an alarm, call cancel() on the Alarm Manager, passing in the PendingIntent you no longer want to fire. For example:

```
   //If the alarm has been set, cancel it.
   if (alarmMgr!= null) {
     alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
   }
```

Comment: you can force close your service via